# Is there a way to change xen_blkfront.max without reboot?

Tags: amazon-web-services, xen, amazon-ebs

This [AWS video](https://youtu.be/1AHmTmCkdp8?t=42m45s) suggests to change `xen_blkfront.max` for better ec2 performance. Is there any way to change this value, considering the below?

- instances are in auto-scaling group, so reboot will fail health check
- we're using default, not custom-built AMI to avoid necessity to rebuild golden image after each change, so prefer stick with the default AWS-provided AMI

Comment: *we're using default, not custom-built AMI to avoid necessity to rebuild golden image after each change,*  Each change?  AMIs don't change.  A change to the official AMI means a different AMI ID.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I meant each change in our ec2 configuration

Comment: Right, so fire up an instance from the default official distro AMI, make this change, create an AMI from it, and use that new AMI instead of the distro AMI to launch.  Since the official distro AMI never changes, yours doesn't need any maintenance, either.

Comment: So far looks like the only solution. Move it to the answer, pls